# Dimension of topology manifold

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, manifolds

In the 3 page of  Jurgen Jost's Riemannian Geometry and Geometric Analysis .Why it is harder in topology manifold  than differentiable manifold ? I think it is easy in differentiable manifold because the Jacobian of chart transition is not zero, so every chart has same dimension . But in topology manifold ,all the open sets are open cover , they must have same dimension, so the topology manifold has same dimension everywhere.

> [image]

Comment: "But in topology manifold ,all the open sets are open cover , they must have same dimension, so the topology manifold has same dimension everywhere. " It is not clear what you mean by this. The "easy" proof in the smooth case involves tangent spaces: we know that if a manifold is locally $n$-euclidean in a point $p$, then $T_pM$ has dimension $n$ as a vector space. The general case uses the theorem of *invariance of domain*, and this is quite more involved to prove. In particular, it might potentially involve the higher dimensional version of the Jordan-Schoenflies theorem.

Comment: One can also use Sperner's lemma and the fact that an $n$-simplex has Lebesgue dimension $n$, but this is still not easy at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To prove that the dimension of a topological manifold is well-defined, you have to prove that $\mathbb{R}^n$ is not locally homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^m$ for $m\neq n$.  This is not at all obvious, and is definitely harder than the simple linear algebra (i.e. vector spaces have well-defined dimension) you can do to show that $\mathbb{R}^n$ is not locally diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^m$.

Comment: For reference, if you want to learn more, this property is called "invariance of domain".